# можно ли передать переменную в значение атрибута title

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, события, атрибуты

```js
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).text();
  alert(a);

});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
         <a href="https://https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">stack</a>
```

Переменная с текстом ссылки есть, но как можно поставить **переменную "a"**(текст ссылки) **в title** ?

Comment: `this.title=` ?

Comment: @splash58 Напишите ответ полностью пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).text();
  this.title = a
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
         <a href="https://https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">stack</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я и сам потом додумался так сделать)

Comment: ну, и отлично! Удачи!